# Evento onchange do datepicker em HTML5

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, mvc

Alguém sabe me informar como faço para usar o evento onchange do datepicker para fazer um verificação na data selecionada?

no meu cshtml está assim:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dat_emissao, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", @onchange = "checkDate2(this.value)" } })
```

e essa seria a minha função:

```
var checkDate2 = function (obj) {
    if (obj._selectedDate > new Date()) {
        alert("Você não pode selecionar uma data maior que a data de hoje!");
        obj._selectedDate = new Date();
        // seleciona a data atual novamente
        obj._textbox.set_Value(obj._selectedDate.format(obj._format))
    }
}
```

Comment: não é só você fazer o bind do método `checkDate2` com a instâcia do elemento, após carregar a página?

Comment: E perceba que na declaração `@onchange = "checkDate2(this.value)` você passa o valor, enquanto seu método espera o objeto

Comment: eu fiz a utilização de uma outra função quase do mesmo jeito e deu certo, só que esse com a data não está indo.

Comment: Exemplo que funciona:

Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Tip_doc, new SelectList(listdoc, "Text", "Value"), "Selecione", new { class = "form-control", onchange = "validateDropDown(this.value)" })"

var validateDropDown = function (obj) {
    if (obj == "C") {
        alert('Selecione um Banco');
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

}

Comment: Você tentou simplesmente o que eu comentei? `@onchange = "checkDate2(this)`? apresente como ficou renderizado o componente no html e faz os testes com o javascript pelo console

Comment: Cheguei cheguei sim Leandro e não foi, então eu acabei fazendo de outra forma, e fiz a chamada no onclick="checkDate2()" que deu certo e agora estou penando para comprar duas data no javascript rsrsr

Comment: Consegui resolver a questão das datas dessa forma:
            var hoje = new Date();
            var emissao = document.getElementById("Emissao").value;
            var emissaolMilissegundos = new Date(emissao).getTime() + 10000000;
            var hojeMilissegundos = new Date(hoje).getTime();

            if (emissaolMilissegundos > hojeMilissegundos) {
                mgs += "Data de EMISSÃO não pode ser maior que a data de hoje!\n";
                erros = erros + 1;
            }

Answer (score 0):

Eu acabei fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
        function VerificaDadosTitulo() {
            var erros = 0;
            var mgs = "";

            var hoje = new Date();
            var emissao = document.getElementById("Emissao").value;
            var vencimento = document.getElementById("Vencimento").value;
            var tipoDoc = document.getElementById("TipoDoc").value;
            var banco = document.getElementById("Banco").value;

            var emissaolMilissegundos = new Date(emissao).getTime() + 10000000;
            var vencimentoMilissegundos = new Date(vencimento).getTime();
            var hojeMilissegundos = new Date(hoje).getTime();

            if ((tipoDoc == "C") && (banco == "")) {
                mgs += "O tipo de documento Cheque, exige que seleciona o banco!\n";
                erros = erros + 1;
            }

            if (tipoDoc == "") {
                mgs += "O tipo de documento é obrigatório!\n";
                erros = erros + 1;
            }

            if (emissaolMilissegundos > hojeMilissegundos) {
                mgs += "Data de EMISSÃO não pode ser maior que a data de hoje!\n";
                erros = erros + 1;
            }
            if (vencimentoMilissegundos < hojeMilissegundos) {
                mgs += "Data de VENCIMENTO não pode ser menor ou igual a data de hoje!\n";
                erros = erros + 1;
            }

            if (erros > 0) {
                alert(mgs);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Incluir" onclick="VerificaDadosTitulo()">
```

Dessa forma deu certo!